# Godot: is_on_floor always false

Tags: collision-detection, godot

This is an extremely simple game (following tutorial).

My code and configuration allows the actor object to fall on a platform made of tilemaps and not fall through, but the function is_on_floor() always outputs false.

```
extends KinematicBody2D
class_name Actor

var velocity: = Vector2.ZERO;
export var gravity: = 3000.0;

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y+=delta*gravity;

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity);
    if is_on_floor():
        print_debug("on floor");
    else:
        print_debug("not on floor"); #only this line prints
```

What's going on? Is the is_on_floor() function usable or do I need to use an alternative way of floor-detection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call `move_and_slide` with only one parameter, all collisions are considered walls. *This is useful in top down games.*

You need to specify an up vector which Godot will use to decide if the collision is a wall, a floor or a ceiling.

For example, like this:

```
velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
```